# Fail to get data field from rest service using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, webclient

everyone! I'm developing this restful web service client, but I'm having an issue trying to get a nested element. This is the XML I'm receiving.

```
<InstalledProducts>
 <InstalledProduct>
 <uri>
 <url>
 http://immix-test.natinst.com/ib-rest/1.0/installed-product/NIC:458513.xml
 </url>
 <urn>urn:installed-product:NIC:458513</urn>
 </uri>
 <instanceId>458513</instanceId>
 <site>NIC</site>
 <serialNumber>A49AD1</serialNumber>
 <productNumber>459513</productNumber>
 <ibStatus>Latest</ibStatus>
 <ibCreationDate>1998-10-14</ibCreationDate>
 <partNumber>
  <urn>urn:product-item:181830E-01</urn>
 </partNumber>
 <latestServiceContracts>
 <url>
 http://immix-test.natinst.com/ib-rest/1.0/installed-product/NIC:458513/latestServiceContracts.xml
 </url>
 </latestServiceContracts>
 <allServiceContracts>
  <url>
   http://immix-test.natinst.com/ib-rest/1.0/installed-product/NIC:458513/allServiceContracts.xml
  </url>
  </allServiceContracts>
 </InstalledProduct>
</InstalledProducts>
```

This is the Java Class that handles the InstalledProduct RootElement

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@XmlRootElement(name = "InstalledProduct")
public class InstalledProductDTO {
private ContractsURL latestServiceContracts;
private PartNumber partNumber;
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(InstalledProductDTO.class);
private int instanceId;
private String status;

@XmlElement(name = "serviceStatus")
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@XmlElement(name = "instanceId")
public int getInstanceId() {
    return instanceId;
}

public void setInstanceId(int instanceId) {
    this.instanceId = instanceId;
}

@XmlElement(name = "partNumber") 
public PartNumber getpartNumberURN(){
    return partNumber;      
}

public void setProductNumber(PartNumber partNumber){
    this.partNumber = partNumber;
}

@XmlElement(name = "latestServiceContracts")
public ContractsURL getLatestServiceContractsURL(){
    return latestServiceContracts;
}

public void setAllServiceContractsURL(ContractsURL latestServiceContractsURL){
    this.latestServiceContracts = latestServiceContractsURL;
}
}
```

and this is the class handling the partNumber tag, which is where the issue is.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "partNumber")
public class PartNumber {

private String urn;

@XmlElement(name = "urn")
public String getURN()
{
    return urn;
}

public void setUrn(String urn){
    this.urn = urn;
}

}
```

When I try to get the partNumber, I'm getting a null. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just solved it. At least this worked for me. 
Check that in the InstalledProductDTO class, the sets and gets for the partNumber xml tag do not match the literal xml tag. The tag is "partNumber", but the get and the set are called getPartNumberURN and setPartNumberURN. So I just changed them to getPartNumber and setPartNumber, and that worked. 
If this worked for you, do let me know to confirm this. If I'm mistaked, please do correct me.
Thanks, and hope this helps!